# Probability Central Limit Application

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots$
  be independent and suppose that $P\left(X_{j}=\sqrt{j}\right)=P\left(X_{j}=-\sqrt{j}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$
  for all $j\in\mathbb{N}
 .$ We want to study the asymptotic distribution of the sample mean $$\overline{X_{n}}=\frac{1}{n}\underset{j=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}}X_{j}
 .$$

Comment: Right, so you want to study it. And the question is?

Comment: The question is if it is a normal (0,2)

Comment: Then you should mention this conjecture in the body of the question. Even more importantly you should mention what you tried, why this failed, which similar problems you can solve, and so on. (And please use @ to answer to comments.)

Comment: @ I applyed Lindeberg CLT, I verified all the conditions and it seems to have a distribution as a Normal(0,2),  in principle you could apply this method to study several problems related to the asymptotic distribution of the sample mean

Comment: Well, if Lindeberg applies, WHAT IS your question?

Comment: @  The point is the following if I know the limit distribution $(as n\rightarrow\infty
 )$ of 
$
\frac{\underset{j=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}}X_{j}}{\sqrt{n\left(n+1\right)}}$, is it like knowing the limit distribution of the sample average?

Comment: Sure, if $Z_n\to Z$ in distribution and $c_n\to1$ then $c_nZ_n\to Z$ in distribution.

Comment: @ ok, great. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome. (By the way, one is supposed to begin a comment with `@name-of-user`, for example `@Did`, not by `@` alone.)

Comment: Of course also in this case the answer it is a normal(0,1/2)

Answer (score 1):

By the central limit theorem:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{j}}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{j}}{\sqrt{n\left(n+1\right)}}\overset{d}{\longrightarrow}N\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$